# Куда выбрасывает exception threadа

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть код который запускает поток который в свою очередь запускает еще один поток. во внутреннем потоке выбрасываю exception и этот exception пишется в консоль, перехватить его не получается. В чем дело, я всегда думал что exception в потоках это ни как не влияет на главный поток. Я считал что только через future можно получить exception в главном потоке.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                thread1.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("1" + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
        try {
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(1);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("3" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

А логах вижу такое

```
1
 Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException
at 
test.lambda$ 
null$0(Test.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так ваш Exception и не вляет на главный поток. Сами посмотрите на вывод. Сначала идет из главного потока

```
1
```

Затем второй поток бросает исключание, которое никак не перехватывается (поэтому то вы и видите эту запись в консоли):

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException
at 
test.lambda$ 
null$0(Test.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

А main продолжает работать как ни в чем не бывало:

```
2
```

А перехватываеть его надо не в main, а в Runnable, то есть тут:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
     throw new RuntimeException();
});
```

И только так:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
     try {
          throw new RuntimeException();
     } catch(...) {}
});
```

Потому что нигде больше вы его не сможете перехватить.

Comment: а здесь пишут что он передается, http://javastudy.ru/interview/concurrent/   34 пункт.

Comment: Мало ли, что там на заборах пишут ) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html - читайте 11.3. Когда в потоке имеет место необработанное исключение, uncaughtException будет вызван. Дальше. переходим сюда: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html - где явно написанно что вызывается виртуальной машиной. я так подозреваю, это происходит в том же потоке, где происзошло исключение.